# Segmentation fault: 11, in C code when trying to print results

Tags: c, fault

I am writing a program in C that will do some logic, but at the moment i am just trying to test that the inputs are being saved correctly. str is supposed to store one of the menu options listed, the unsigned int hex is supposed to store a hex value, and the int is storing a decimal value.

Below is the code:

```
int main()
{
  char str[2];
  unsigned int hex;
  int decimal;

  printf("Choose an Option (C, M, Q, S, V): ");
  scanf("%s", &str);

  printf("Enter a value for x: ");
  scanf("%u", &hex);

  printf("Enter a value for n: ");
  scanf("%d",decimal);

  printf("Testing: %s, %u, %d\n",str,hex,decimal);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile it on my terminal it gives me no errors, and it even runs through all the inputs i ask of it. The output looks like this:

```
Enter a value for x: 1
Enter a value for n: 1
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Why am I getting segmentation fault 11? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just a comment on scanf or sscanf. Whenever you use a string conversion, aka "%s", get into the habit of putting a limit on it. You could use `scanf("%1s", str)` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is not needed here:

```
scanf("%s", &str);
```

And `&` is needed here:

```
scanf("%d",decimal);
```

Comment: Would be worth explaining why? `scanf()` requiring a pointer-to-type as it parameter and [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) applying to the array.

Comment: Why not select this answer as the solution, then?